# How can I assign unique IDs based on a record identifier in R?

Tags: r, data-import

My mission: tally up budget and revenue numbers based on movie data.

I'm reading in data from a text file that basically comes in the format:

```
MV,Movie 1 Name
BT,Budget for Movie 1
GR,Gross Revenue Movie 1
```

but the data may or may not contain BT or GR, or sometimes contain multiples, for example:

```
MV,Movie1
BT,1000000
GR,500000 (week1)
GR,500000 (week2)
GR,500000 (week3)
GR,500000 (week1)
MV,Movie2
BT,10000
GR,50000 (week1)
GR,500000 (week2)
MV,Movie3
MV,Movie4
BT,1000000
```

What I'd like to create is a dataframe that looks like:

```
mID  recType  recData
  1  MV       Movie1
  1  BT       1000000
  1  GR       500000 (week1)
  1  GR       500000 (week2)
  1  GR       500000 (week3)
  1  GR       500000 (week1)
  2  MV       Movie2
  2  BT       10000
  2  GR       50000 (week1)
  2  GR       500000 (week2)
  3  MV       Movie3
  4  MV       Movie4
  4  BT       1000000
```

The programmer in me says to just write a data-cleansing application in java or .NET to clean up the data prior to bringing it into R, but I wanted to see if the collective intelligence of the Internet could help me out.

Writing a loop for this, for over 90K movies, was pretty obnoxiously long in processing.

Note: the ultimate goal of this is to use this data as a main source for classifying profitability of movies and cross-reference this with external files for genre, actors, and other data.

(IMDB needs to have a little better data setup)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
df1$mID <- cumsum(grepl('^Movie', df1$recData))
#df1$mID <- cumsum(df1$recType=='MV')
df1[,c(3,1:2)]
#   mID recType        recData
#1    1      MV         Movie1
#2    1      BT        1000000
#3    1      GR 500000 (week1)
#4    1      GR 500000 (week2)
#5    1      GR 500000 (week3)
#6    1      GR 500000 (week1)
#7    2      MV         Movie2
#8    2      BT          10000
#9    2      GR  50000 (week1)
#10   2      GR 500000 (week2)
#11   3      MV         Movie3
#12   4      MV         Movie4
#13   4      BT        1000000
```

Or using `data.table` (would be faster)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, mID:= cumsum(recType=='MV')][]
```